# Subtract two rows with same 2 cell values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

# first dataframe
A = pd.DataFrame({'clients':[123, 123, 124, 124], 'Product':['stock', 'bonds','stocks','bonds'], 'net':[100, 0, 300, 200]}, index = [0, 1, 2, 4])

    clients    Product  net
0      123      stock   100
1      123      bonds    0
2      124      stocks  300
4      124      bonds   200

# second dataframe
B = pd.DataFrame({'clients':[123, 123, 124, 124], 'Product':['bonds', 'stocks','stocks','bonds'], 'net':[100, 50, 250, 100]}, index = [0, 2, 3, 5])
 
     clients    Product   net
0      123      bonds    100
2      123      stocks   50
3      124      stocks   250
5      124      bonds    100
```

I want to subtract ('B - A') only the same product net value of a given client, but I have an index problem as you notice above. I want the output to be:

```
     clients    Product   net difference
?      123      stocks         -50
?      123      bonds         100
?      124      stocks        -50
?      124      bonds         -100
```

I used '?' in the indexes, because I don't care about them.

Comment: I assume `stock` in `A` is a typo, intended to be `stocks`?

Comment: Is this information coming from a database?  Because this would be better handled by the database server before you get it into pandas.

Comment: `A.set_index(['clients','Product']).sub(B.set_index(['clients', 'Product']))`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `sort_values` and `reset_index`:

```
A = A.sort_values(['clients', 'Product'])
B = B.sort_values(['clients', 'Product'])

A = A.reset_index(drop=True)
A['net'] = B['net'].reset_index(drop=True) - A['net'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> A
   clients Product  net
0      123   bonds  100
1      123  stocks  -50
2      124   bonds -100
3      124  stocks  -50
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform unambiguous operations, you need to align the values. `merge` is one option:

```
(A.merge(B, on=['clients', 'Product'])
  .assign(**{'net difference': lambda d: d['net_y']-d['net_x']})
  .drop(columns=['net_x', 'net_y'])
 )
```

Alternative, setting a temporary index:

```
cols = ['clients', 'Product']
((B.set_index(cols)-A.set_index(cols))
 .rename({'net': 'net difference'})
 .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   clients Product  net difference
0      123  stocks             -50
1      123   bonds             100
2      124  stocks             -50
3      124   bonds            -100
```